# Trimming telephone number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below column

| TEL |
| --- |
| +440555123123 |
| 4+40555123123 |
| 0440555123123 |
| 00440555123123 |
| 440555123123 |
| 4455512443123 |
| +055512443123 |
| 055512443123 |

I would like to remove the leading +|0|4 , with the below desired output. Also, if, after doing the replace, the number does not have a leading 0, then add it.

| TEL |
| --- |
| 0555123123 |
| 0555123123 |
| 0555123123 |
| 0555123123 |
| 0555123123 |
| 055512443123 |
| 055512443123 |
| 055512443123 |

Comment: Your rules and your examples don't fully match.

Comment: What's the mismatch?

Comment: @Ivar oh, sorry, that's the question amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your area code will not start with `0` or `4` and you are just removing the international prefix, you can use:

```sql
SELECT tel,
       '0' || LTRIM( tel, '+04' ) AS normalised_tel
FROM   TABLE_NAME;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( TEL ) AS
SELECT '+440555123123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4+40555123123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0440555123123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00440555123123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '440555123123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4455512443123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '+055512443123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '055512443123' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TEL | NORMALISED_TEL |
> | --- | --- |
> | +440555123123 | 0555123123 |
> | 4+40555123123 | 0555123123 |
> | 0440555123123 | 0555123123 |
> | 00440555123123 | 0555123123 |
> | 440555123123 | 0555123123 |
> | 4455512443123 | 055512443123 |
> | +055512443123 | 055512443123 |
> | 055512443123 | 055512443123 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9fadbd1ba21fcb3b20fc5cf8817c329)*

Answer (score 2):

I would explicitly list out the prefixes you want to get rid of -- even your question misses what they are.  This seems like it might be tricky, so being explicit seems important.

You can use a lateral join to fix the prefix.  Then a `case` expression to add the leading `0`:

```
select t.*, 
       (case when tt.tel2 like '0%' then tt.tel2 else '0' || tt.tel2 end)
from t cross join lateral
     (select regexp_replace(tel, '^([+]44|4[+]4|044|44|[+])', '') as tel2 from dual) tt
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d456e31478948f94382e5c0f826f3aa6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: 4455512443123 for this one, it will remove the 44 in between the string.